# How many AWS Cognito app clients are needed when you have multiple apps(web/mobil) using the same user pool , each with its own backend application.?

Tags: oauth-2.0, amazon-cognito

I am currently building an Auth solution with OAuth 2 and Cognito. We have a suite of applications and each application has its own frontend web app and its own single backend service. The backend services across products communicate with each other some times. All of this products utilises the same user pool. Given that using an API gateway is not an option , which option would be applicable for my use case -

1. Cognito app client per application.
2. Cognito app client per client (web , mobile etc)

In case we use a single Cogntio app client for all the web applications - the callback url configuration could be an issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have multiple callback URLs defined in your App client separated by commas. Just make sure that it matches exactly where your application is.

[image]

Source: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/limits.html

Comment: Thanks Ninad!. I understand that , but then my callback urls would contain urls from different services when only one of them really needs to be invoked. For eg - firstbackend/callback, secondbackend/callback, thirdbacked/callback . If the secured resource is in firstbackend then too other urls will be invoked.

Comment: You can form your own URL in front end and select the callback URL you need, right?

Comment: I have multiple frontend and multiple backends with a common Authorization server, request originating from frontend 1 should only be redirected to its backends server.

Comment: The URL that you create for authentication has the callback URL specified in it at the end. If you have multiple callback URLs defined in your settings, You can specify any one of these URLs in your authentication URL and after authenticting, it will redirect to the URL you specified.